# Unhide Right Bar in xcode xib file

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xib

I am new to iOS development. I am not able to see the right bar form which we drag items to xib files.. How can i bring it back ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two options:

1. From the Xcode menu, select: View -> Utilities -> Show Utilities
2. Press the Utilities icon in the top right corner to show it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Click on the marked area in my screenshot in Xcode (top right corner)

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

see the top right corner of Xcode there you will see the 3 rectangles
click 3rd rectangle. click the mouse pointer over there you will tip "Hide or show the utilities".

Answer (score 1):

Click on click 3rd rectangle on top right corner of Xcode there you will see the 3 rectangles